# Error uploading file with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, express

Using the code below, when I try uploading a file, the browser just keeps loading forever. Any idea why?

**app.js**

```js
var formidable = require('formidable'),
    http = require('http'),
    util = require('util');

app.get('/song/add', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(
        '<form action="/song/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
        '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
        '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
        '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
        '</form>'
    );
});

app.post('/song/upload', function (req, res) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('received upload:\n\n');
        res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove that line( `app.use(express.bodyParser())` ) in your code, that should work I believe.

But why do you want to use formidable? I believe express body parser is based on formidable, and it is more cleaner to use. Since it even parses other types of body, beside the forms type like JSON, but formidable will throw an error if the body type is not supported. If you have `app.use(express.bodyParser())` in your code, then you can do this to get what you want:

```
app.post('/song/upload', function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('received upload:\n\n');
    res.end(util.inspect(req.body));
    return;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the express body parser option turned on. Check your config for something like:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser())
```

I think the problem is that Formidable is expecting stream events for this file & they've already been consumed by Express by the time your `app.post` callback is called. Since the `form.parse` callback only fires on `end` no response is ever rendered.

The solution would be to use Express or Formidable, you can disable the config option if you want to use Formidable.

Comment: I had turn on `app.use(express.bodyParser())` in my code.. Could u tell me detail of **disable the config option if you want to use Formidable**

Comment: If you want to use **Formidable** (behind the scene) along with **Express** (without `app.use(express.bodyParser()`), you could use **[connect-form](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-form)**. But this module, according the author, is now deprecated. See [Form Handling - Processing in Express.js](http://www.hacksparrow.com/form-handling-processing-in-express-js.html) for a nice explanation on this subject.

Comment: See [Handle File Uploads in Express (Node.js)](http://www.hacksparrow.com/handle-file-uploads-in-express-node-js.html) too. It is the sequel of the above mentioned article.

Answer (score 0):

The problem what I see here is new body parser (since Connect 1.8.0). If you want to use new Connect with formidable you need to delete multipart parser from body parser:

```
delete express.bodyParser.parse['multipart/form-data'];
```

Comment: When I try to add this line of code it crashes my app - I get: 

/Code/myApp/server/main.js:6
delete express.bodyParser.parse['multipart/form-data'];
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot convert null to object
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Code/myApp/server/main.js:6:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    etc

Answer (score 0):

Don't use bodyParser with Express 4.x:
http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html

use

> app.use(express.json());
>
> app.use(express.urlencoded());

instead. The problem with your code is that you will return before the callback will be called so the result will not be send to the user.

Change your code to:

> return res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));

and remove the return at the end.